# What is wrong with this simple todo list application I made?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="TestCSS.css">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Monoton&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<script src="TestJS.js"></script>
<div class="main">
<h1 class="header"> Todo list </h1>
<div class="inputs">
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter your tasks" class="inpt" id="inpt">
<button class="btn" id="btn"> Add </button>
</div>
<div id="tasks" >  
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>


let theButton = document.getElementById("btn");
let theInput = document.getElementById("inpt");
let theField = document.getElementById("tasks");

document.onload = ()=> {
    theButton.addEventListener('click',
    function func(){
        var task = document.createElement("p");
        task.innerText = theInput.value; 
         theField.appendChild(task);
        }
    )
}
```

I have no idea what is wrong with this code, sorry if I seem stupid I am new in the programming world and this is my very first application.

Comment: _"What is wrong?"_ You tell me !

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please take some time to read the guidelines and on How to ask a question. SO is not a forum, tutorial, guide or personal help desk. Stating soemthing is wrong is not just broad but a compeltely useless information. How should we know what is not working as intend or broken? So edit your question with far more detailed informations. For example what is not working as intended and what the desired behavior should be.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that `document` does not raise the `onload` event - `window` does (among others - documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload)) so your code was never adding the event listener to your button.

You can debug such issues simply by adding a `console.log("Foo")` inside the event handler - you would have noticed it was never written to the log when you clicked the button.

```js
let theButton = document.getElementById("btn");
let theInput = document.getElementById("inpt");
let theField = document.getElementById("tasks");

window.onload = ()=> {
    theButton.addEventListener('click',
    function func(){
        var task = document.createElement("p");
        task.innerText = theInput.value; 
         theField.appendChild(task);
        }
    )
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
<h1 class="header"> Todo list </h1>
<div class="inputs">
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter your tasks" class="inpt" id="inpt">
<button class="btn" id="btn"> Add </button>
</div>
<div id="tasks" >  
</div>
</div>
```